# ASP Template Column Sorting Alphanumbical and Dates

Tags: asp.net, sorting, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a snippet of code that I need to sort multiple columns. The column headers are:

- Trade Reference
- Settlement Date
- Currency
- Commission
- Payment Status

I am using `AllowSorting="True"` in the asp:datagrid header. Then in each of the asp:TemplateColumn I am using `SortExpression="tra_settlement_date"`

I can't get the columns to sort either by A-Z / 1-10etc for the columns either from newest to oldest / Z-A. The page thinks, but it doesn't resort the items.

Here are the first two columns of the table.

```
<asp:datagrid
  ID="dgrStatement"
  runat="server"
  runat="server"
  CellPadding="4"
  AllowSorting="True"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  Font-Bold="False"
  Font-Italic="False"
  Font-Names="Calibri"
  Font-Overline="False"
  Font-Strikeout="False"
  Font-Underline="False"
  GridLines="None"
  ForeColor="#333333"
  cssclass="figures statements-tbody statements-tbody-y"
>
  <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn
      Visible="False"
      DataField="tra_id"
      HeaderText="ID"
    ></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn
      SortExpression="[trade reference]"
      HeaderText="Trade Reference"
    >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label
          id="lblRef"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.[trade reference]") %>'
        >
        </asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox
          id="Textbox13"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.[trade reference]") %>'
        >
        </asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle
        Font-Bold="False"
        Font-Italic="False"
        Font-Overline="False"
        Font-Strikeout="False"
        Font-Underline="False"
      />
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn
      SortExpression="tra_settlement_date"
      HeaderText="Settlement Date"
    >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label
          id="lblSettlDate"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# Date.ParseExact(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.tra_settlement_date"),"yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).tostring("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'
        >
        </asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox
          id="Textbox1"
          runat="server"
          Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.tra_settlement_date") %>'
        >
        </asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
  </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Have you added `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, just ends up replicating the same data over and over

Comment: Kindly share your code, that would be better to understand.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the original question

Comment: Change your `DataGrid` to `GridView`, and try again.

Comment: I get a Parsing Error due to the BoundColumns

Comment: Data Grid use BoundColumns and GridView use BoundField, you may replace `BoundColumn` with `BoundField`.